# Fixed Height and Width Spire BarCode C#

Tags: c#, fonts, barcode, font-size, spire

I am facing issue with the spire barcode generation with fontsize . When ever input of barcode increase from 5 the size of image increases , I need to adjust it to the fix dimension.

```
BarcodeSettings settings = new BarcodeSettings();
            settings.Data = AccessionNo;
            settings.HasBorder = false;
            settings.ShowText = true;
            settings.ShowTextOnBottom = true;
            settings.TextAlignment = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            settings.TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            settings.Type = Spire.Barcode.BarCodeType.Code128;
            settings.Code128SetMode = Code128SetMode.OnlyA;
            settings.TextFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Helvetica", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
            string  resultString = Regex.Match(AccessionNo, @"\d+").Value;

            //if(Convert.ToInt32(resultString) > 9)
            //{
            //   settings.TextFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Helvetica", 7, FontStyle.Regular);
            //  settings.DpiX = 121;
            //settings.DpiY = 121;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //settings.TextFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Helvetica", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
            //settings.DpiX = 140;
            //settings.DpiY = 140;
            //}

            settings.DpiX = 121;
            settings.DpiY = 121;
            settings.Unit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
            settings.BarHeight = 6;
            settings.TopMargin = 0f;
            settings.LeftMargin = 0f;
            settings.RightMargin = 0f;
            settings.BottomMargin = 0f;

            settings.ShowTopText = false;




            System.Drawing.Image barcode = null;


    `
```

Answer (score -1):

Before setting the height and width, you need to add this line of code: **settings.AutoResize = false;**

Example:

```
            int width = 400;
            int height = 200;               

            settings.AutoResize = false;

            settings.X = 3.0f;

            //Bar height
            settings.BarHeight = height * 0.6f;

            //Image width and height
            settings.ImageWidth = width;
            settings.ImageHeight = height;

            //....
```